# Permanently enable RHEL scl

Tags: redhat, rhel, software-collections, rhel-scl

Is there a way to permanently enable custom Software Collections for RedHat?

I have installed an scl to provide python27 in RHEL6 and don't want to have to enable the custom scl every time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, you could add something to your startup script to source the enable script.

Eg add to your `.bash_profile` (note space between initial `dot` and `/`)

```
. /opt/rh/python27/enable
```

Comment: Putting it to /etc/profile.d/ is [much better solution](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2014/03/19/permanently-enable-a-software-collection/). What if the person is not a bash user?

Answer (score 4):

This option sounds dangerous to me for root. I would think something like the following would be safer and more appropriate:

You can create a function that takes command line options. Think of this as an alias on steroids. Add the following to your .bashrc

```
python27() {
scl enable python27 “python $*”
}
```

Then test:

```
python27 –version
Python 2.7.5
```

This doesn’t help with your magic line in scripts, but will make it easier to call scripts:

```
[smccarty@keith ~]$ cat script.py
#!/usr/bin/env python27

import sys

print “Hello, World!”, sys.version
```

Call it normal and notice, the default installation of python is used:

```
[smccarty@keith ~]$ ./script.py
Hello, World! 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 4 2013, 07:46:00)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)]
```

Call it with our alias, and notice that Python 2.7 is used:

```
[smccarty@keith ~]$ python27 script.py
Hello, World! 2.7.5 (default, May 23 2013, 06:08:09)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)]
```

Comment: It seems to break if script.py is renamed to a name containing a space, like "abc def.py"

Answer (score 0):

#### In a nutshell: `source scl_source enable name`

- to find the `name` you can do `scl --list`

---

---

---

#### longer story:

In your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` or `/etc/profile.d/enable_name.sh`

```
if command -v scl_source &>/dev/null; then
    source scl_source enable name
fi
```

Hat tip to:

- [solution in unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175851/how-to-permanently-enable-scl-centos-6-4)
- [solution in serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/751155/permanently-enable-a-scl)
- [solution in redhat.com](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/527703)

#### **p.s. do not use any solution that spawns a new shell because it can [Forkbomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) you and prevent you from being able to login**

- for more information on avoiding the ForkBomb read [here1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175851/how-to-permanently-enable-scl-centos-6-4) and [here2](https://serverfault.com/questions/751155/permanently-enable-a-scl)

#### p.s. SCL goes away in EnterpriseLinux version >= el8