# On el8/el9/newer, how do you get newer versions of software like python3, gcc, java, etc?

Tags: linux, rhel, dnf

For example on el7:

- to develop an nvidia CUDA application you need a newer gcc than the default gcc version 4.8.x and to get the newer version you would use a software repo called "Software Collections" (SCL)
- the base python3 is 3.6 and you need newer python modules and so you install python3.8 from SCL

Starting on el8, and el9: the SCL is deprecated and so there is a different method for installing and configuring newer versions of gcc and python3.

#### On el8/el9/newer, how do you get newer versions of software like python3, gcc, java, etc?

Answer (score 0):

## in a nutshell, here are some examples for how to install and configure

- for python3 to get python3.9: `dnf install -y python39 && alternatives --set python3 $(command -v python3.9)`
- for gcc to get gcc-12: `dnf install gcc-toolset-12 && source scl_source enable gcc-toolset-12`
- for java to get java-17: `dnf install java-17 && bin_java_filename=$(rpm -qa|grep java-17|xargs rpm -ql|grep "bin\/java$"|head -1) && alternatives --set java ${bin_java_filename}`
- tested on rocky8, rocky9

---

### which repo has the newer software versions?

- the old method using "SCL" was deprecated
- the new method is to use a repo called "appstream"
- here is a post written by the distro maintainers explaining the change https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/11/15/rhel8-introducing-appstreams
- the repo is enabled by default

### how to: install newer software versions?

- for python3: `dnf install python39`
- for gcc: `dnf install gcc-toolset-12`

### how to: change the system default?

- for python3: `alternatives --set python3 $(command -v python3.9)`
- for gcc:

  - edit your user `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` or create a new file under `/etc/profile.d/` with the following: `source scl_source enable gcc-toolset-12`
  - i thought `scl_source` would go away in el8, el9 but apparently not
  - for more info on `scl_source` go to this link https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195219/5510 or [Permanently enable RHEL scl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264601/permanently-enable-rhel-scl/75260721#75260721)

### p.s. what is the difference between `alternatives` and `update-alternatives`?

- the original tool is called `update-alternatives` and is from Debian linux distro
- in EnterpriseLinux, Redhat rewrote the tool and called it `alternatives` and when you install `alternatives` the package also installs a symlink with name `update-alternatives` on your env var `PATH` to help you find the tool
- the two are similar but not the same because their source code is different